# Can I use ECDSA certificate to generate signature with xades4j?

Tags: java, xades4j, xades

I'm trying to digitally sign an xml document with **xades4j**, but I get an exception "**UnsupportedAlgorithmException**: Signature algorithm not supported by the provider (EC)"
when I use EC certificate, however the exception goes when user RSA.

Is there a way to add a support for the EC Certificate ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. The way to do it has been discussed in this issue: https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/issues/225